# I have this PHP form processing file which is works but with 2 issues that I can't solve

Tags: php, contact-form

I have this PHP form processing file which is works but with 2 issues that I can't solve:

1. Doesn't send an email if submitted from a mobile device
2. When receiving an email on Gmail have a yellow alert message because google can't verify if email has been sent from the real email

Please could someone check it?

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['invio-form'])) 
{
    $nome               = $_POST['nome'];
    $azienda            = $_POST['azienda'];
    $telefono           = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email              = $_POST['email'];
    $messaggio          = $_POST['messaggio'];
    $acconsento         = $_POST['acconsento'];

    if (!ctype_alpha(str_replace(array(' ', "'", '-'), '', $nome))) {
        header('location:/?errore-nome');
    }
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header('location:/?errore-email');
    }
    else {
        $to             = "myemail@email.com";
        $subject        = 'Landing page - Ci ha contattato un nuovo LEAD';

        $headers        = "From: $nome - $email \r\n";
        $headers        .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
        $headers        .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers        .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        $message        = "<html><body>";
        $message        .= "<h1>Riepilogo dati utente: \r\n</h1>";
        $message        .= "<hr>\r\n";
        $message        .= "<p style='font-size: 18px;'>Email ricevuta da: <strong>$email</strong> \r\n</p>";
        $message        .= "<p style='font-size: 18px;'>Nome utente: $nome \r\n</p>";
        $message        .= "<p style='font-size: 18px;'>Azienda: $azienda \r\n</p>";
        $message        .= "<p style='font-size: 18px;'>Numero di telefono: $telefono \r\n</p>";
        $message        .= "<p style='font-size: 18px;'>Utente ha scritto: $messaggio</p>";
        $message        .= "<hr>\r\n";
        $message        .= "<p style='font-size: 18px;'>Utente ha aderito al trattamento dei dati personali \r\n</p>";
        $message        .= "</html></body>";

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            header('location:/?grazie');
            }
        }
    }




?>
```

Comment: I advise you to use PhpMailer, research on how to send an email using PhpMailer with composer, it can save your life!

Comment: If I were to lookup a from address, I'd likely find a different server than the one you are sending from.  My advice is to not spoof the from address (use the server's valid address). You have the email given the Reply-To header.   Caution: you are open to email header injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect "From:" header. Email address should be in format `$nome <$email>\r\n`. See RFC2822. In some cases $nome must be in quotes. And "From:" email shall be the same host as a sender, i.e. - your's.

```
if(preg_match('/["(),.:;<>@[\\\\\]]/', $nome))
{
    $nome = '"'.addcslashes($nome, '"(),.:;<>@[\]').'"';
}

$address = sprintf('%s <%s>', $nome, $email);
```

Comment: Yeah, you were right! I can't receive an email if sent from a different host... Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Afraid no, it is "protection" from spam.

Comment: so need to use some services like postmark for example, right?